# Calling TransactionScope.Complete when executing multiple sql statements in DAL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I was reading up on this and it seemed like I shouldn't have to call scope.Complete for the following code to work.

When I try running this without using scope.Complete() the records are saved to the database. If scope.Complete() is there the records save and everything works.

```
public static void SaveProducts(IList<Product> products)
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (var connection = GetOpenConnection())
        {
            StringBuilder sqlDelete = new StringBuilder();
            sqlDelete.AppendLine("MY SQL STATEMENT HERE ");

            StringBuilder sqlInsert = new StringBuilder();
            sqlInsert.AppendLine("MY SQL STATEMENT HERE ");


            connection.Execute(sqlDelete.ToString(), new { CategoryId = categoryId });
            connection.Execute(sqlInsert.ToString(), products);

        }

        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I misread your original statement and went with context...are you saying that the records **are** saved if you **don't** call scope.Complete()? Actually, I didn't misread it...it seems to be contradictory: "When I try running this without using scope.Complete() the records are saved to the database, when it isn't there nothing happens." Both are saying when scope.Complete isn't there!

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that when I do not call scope.Complete(), nothing happens. I updated my post, sorry it has been a long day.

Comment: I got confused for a sec! I would also point out that you should be careful with adding the strings like this and be sure that you use parameterized queries. Otherwise, you'll be susceptible to sql injection.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you are saying, but I am using Dapper so shouldn't that handle sql injection? My queries all use parameters as you can see in my example I am sending in categoryId which replaces @CategoryId in the query. Does this make sense?

Comment: I think I was just focusing in on the StringBuilder class + SQL which to me equals danger! I've never used Dapper before, but if that is how they do parameterized queries, then you should be good-to-go. (Dapper should be fine for combating SQL injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653461/dapper-and-sql-injections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Failing to call this method aborts the transaction, because the transaction manager interprets this as a system failure, or exceptions thrown within the scope of transaction.

I think it's saying that if there is something that goes wrong, it will be disposed before the complete is signaled.