# Insert query is not inserting session ID in the database table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

As you can check in attached screenshot that null values are inserted instead of Actual Value
[image: Screenshot]

I have an INSERT query further bound with Gridview

The query is:

```
string cmdStr = fun.insert("SD_Cust_Quotation_Details_Temp", 
    "SessionId,CompId,FinYearId,ItemDesc,TotalQty,Rate", 
    "'" + SId + "','" + CompId + "','" + FinYearId + "','" + ProductName + "','" + Qty + "','" + r + "'");
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at this line, what is the value of `SId`?

Comment: It shows NULL Value.

Comment: So this is your answer, you send a null to DB so you get a null in DB

Comment: You should really be parametrising your code. That looks very only to open to injection

Comment: The **above code** should not be causing a `NULL` to be inserted (it can't, it has quotes around it - so it would be inserting `''` instead). For us to be 100% sure though, you'd need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You should change `SessionID` in the `SD_Cust_Quotation_Details_Temp` table to be `NOT NULL`able so you can find the exact code that is inserting those `NULL`s. Then, consider using Dapper or PetaPoco or the like to handle data insertion, so it can handle `NULL`s for you. Your code, as is, is open to SQL Injection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dapper and SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653461/dapper-and-sql-injections)

Comment: @mjwills, true, probably it's the string 'NULL' and not a real DBNull.

Comment: That is possible, yes @yv989c.