# Is using dapper in this way considered inline SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I've been using Dapper like this to do queries (simplified psudeo-code):

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;"
using (Connection)
{
    return Connection.Query<Employee>(sql);
}
```

I was wondering if this is considered "inline SQL", which is bad according to a lot of people.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653461/dapper-and-sql-injections

Comment: I'd also consider utilising Dapper.Contrib https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/08/05/dapper-in-net-core-part-4-dapper-contrib/

Comment: The inline SQL that most people consider bad is when the SQL is generated dynamically. You should be able to pass a `const string sql` to `Query()`, no formatting/interpolation, no `+`, no `string.Join`. The above is not a problem. Other issues: don't use `select *`, specify the exact columns you need. Don't cache connection objects, create a new one every time from connection string

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is inline SQL. However, inline SQL isn't "bad" in any way; the only truly "bad" thing is not using parameters, which is something Dapper makes trivial to get right. Most arguments against inline SQL are falsely equating the two concepts. There are discussions about the pros/cons of stored procedures vs inline SQL, but it is subjective and there very much are pros and cons of each. Plus Dapper can use stored procedures *anyway*.

It isn't *exactly* the same, but there's a lot of crossover with my thoughts here: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/12/dapper-prepared-statements-and-car-tyres.html

Answer (score 0):

Inline sql will require sql server to compile an execution plan, deciding on indexes, meaning a processing overhead on every call.
Stored procedures are precompiled.
Also any amendment to the query does not necessarily mean recompiling and deploying a new branch.
A SP will let you do serverside processing on the results, including more complex transaction handling.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!